# CUDA : can device and code run parallelly till lifetime, ping-ponging data?

Tags: cuda, ipc

I am programming matrix vector multiplications with Cuda. The matrix is in blocks, so every thread can hold one block of the matrix in the shared memory (as thread local variables). I also send the vector as an argument, the multiplications is carried out in blocks, no problem. But the problem is a time dependant problem. I have to compute the matrix vector product with the same matrix, but different vector for each time slice. So it would be a waste to call the kernel for every product evaluation, causing a copy of the matrix blocks from the graphic card's global memory to the shared memory. I thought I could make one kernel call, and keep it alive always, thereby not losing the thread local variables. The vector can be allocated as a mapped memory in the host, say V. Now the kernel multiplies, saves it in yet another mapped region, say P, sets a flag (another integer mapped memory). The host polls on the flag, once the flag is set, it displays the product from P, loads new vector into V, and resets the flag. The kernel also polls the flag, sees reset, multiplies, saves product in P and sets the flag.

I wrote a smaller addition program to see if such an interprocess communication works, it doesnt. The problem is, when a kernel writes anything into a mapped memory, the memory in the host is not updated until the host the calls cudaThreadSynchronize(); But if the thread synchronisation can not happen as long as kernel is polling on the flag.  Is there a way out of this situation?

Is there any other non-ugly method of realizing such an interprocess communication.
Of course, the manuals say that mapped memory helps to amortize latency, that to for one time copying. Since they did not explain the underlying mechanism that imposes such a restriction, I gave a shot to this idea.

Any help is welcome.

Thank you,

Elan.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I entirely understand your problem, but yes, you can have multiple concurrent kernels active.

From the CUDA computing Guide v. 3.2 pg. 38:
http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/3_2/toolkit/docs/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf

> Some devices of compute capability 2.x can execute multiple kernels
>   concurrently.  Applications may query this capability by calling
>   cudaGetDeviceProperties() and checking the  concurrentKernels
>   property.

My question for you is why do you want to use multiple kernels?

I think you need to reread the CUDA guide (see above).  It sounds like what you want to do is a single kernel with multiple blocks/threads, with each block having its own chunk of shared memory.  Next you need to figure out how big an element to use for each block.  Remember you need two "chunks" of memory and a product (3 equal size square 2D matrices).  To do this query your device and get the compute capacity and read the above guide to determine the resulting amount of shared memory.

Then use a code like:

```
if (ComputeCapability >= 2.0)
   {
      NumberOfSharedValues = (32768/GetSize(Dummy));
      FullUseageThreadsPerBlock = 512;
      MaxBlocksPerSM = 3;
   }
   else
   {
      //Tot. Shared mem / Size per var / Number of Arrays
      NumberOfSharedValues = (16384/GetSize(Dummy)/3);

      //CC1.2 && CC1.3
      if (ComputeCapability >= 1.2)
      {
         FullUseageThreadsPerBlock = 512;
         MaxBlocksPerSM = 2;
      }  
      else  //CC1.0 && CC1.1
      {
         FullUseageThreadsPerBlock = 256;
         MaxBlocksPerSM = 3;
      }   
   }
```

Where `Dummy` is of the templated type and I've written functions to return the sizes of common templated types (e.g. int, float, double) in CUDA (e.g. in C and int is typically 16 bits, in CUDA its 32 bit).

Copy the arrays to multiply into global memory on the device.

Then take the square root of your `NumberOfSharedValues` variable, and write a kernel that declares three arrays in shared memory of that length (the two "chunks" and the product).

Have the kernel copy the chunks to multiply into the shared memory, do the multiplication, then write the resulting "product" chunk back to global memory.

Finally, read the global product array back to the host.

Voila, I think that should do the trick for you.

Bear in mind that you'll be assigning the shared memory described above is the amount available to a single multiprocessor (and since each of your blocks is allocating this much memory, the blocks = # multiprocessors), so  your total size of elements you can be processing at once will be a function of how many multiprocessors you have, again a queryable quantity.

Also be aware, that you may want to use `cuMemGetInfo` to get the amount of free memory, to make sure you can fit your who array into global memory.

Again reading the guide and looking @ the examples NVIDIA published are critical to understanding the memory hierarchy on the device and writing good kernels.

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I am sorry that my question was not so clear. The approach you outlined, is what I am doing. I have just one kernel, multiple blocks. To reword my question from the example you made: 
'Finally, read the global product array back to the host.' At this point, the threads on the GPU are dissolved, since the kernel context has been executed. Now for the next time step, I have to initiate multiplication. That implies calling the kernel again from the host. The threads are created, data is copied from GPU global memory to threads. This is what I wish to avoid.

Comment: Is the following possible?
1.Copy matrix to GPU. Host initiates kernel to multiply with vector V.
2.Kernel computes the product, copies result to host (realized with mapped mem?) but does not terminate 
3.Host reads result (learns via flag?), displays it, writes new V into device (with mapped mem?)
4.Still running kernel learns new data has arrived (via flag), multiplies (main goal/saving is here: it does not have to load matrix from GPU main mem), writes result into host, sets a flag to announce and waits on flag for new V.
Is there a way to achieve this IPC? I hope the question is clearer no